# How to resolve peer unverified exception in a secure nifi cluster?

Tags: ssl, apache-nifi, tls1.2

I set up a secured NiFi cluster with TLS certificates provided by the organisation.On accessing the UI I am getting the error as "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname abc.com not verified: certificate: sha256/abc/abcabc= DN: CN=abc.com, OU=Abc Operations, O=Abc Corporation Limited, C=SG subjectAltNames: [abc.com]".I have referred the link https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/walkthroughs.html#securing-nifi-with-provided-certificates.
Is there anything I missed to enable peer to peer communication while using SSL?

Comment: Does the subject alternative name for the server certificate match the hostname you are using to access the NiFi UI? Are any wildcards being used in the DN or alt names? What version of NiFi and what version of Java are you using?

Comment: NiFi Version-1.12.1 
java version - 1.8.0_271. The subject alternative name given in the certificate is hostname. I am trying to access the NiFi UI using the ipaddress. No wildcards are being used in DN or alt names.

Comment: If the IP address is not in the certificate SAN, then you may not be able to access it using the IP. Does the UI work when using the hostname?

Comment: When I set up a standalone NiFi instance it works and I can access the UI giving ip. The issue occurs when I set up the two node NiFi cluster. Nifi is running on AWS ec2 instances. The issue seems like certificate of one node cannot be verified by the other. Is there any restrictions for transfer of certificates between nodes on ec2.

Comment: As long as the CA for both certificates is in the truststore on both nodes, it should be fine. Is the nifi.properties value nifi.cluster.node.address an IP address or the hostname? This likely also needs to match the SAN for the certificate (it should be the hostname for the node).

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and found solution in **NiFi TLS-toolkit**.

**Notion**: on my cluster auth worked correctly and problem was only in java verification SSL

**Shortly**: problem indeed in `--subjectAlternativeNames`

Generating ssl-keys with own rootCA not worked for me. Good instrunction (but old): https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-create-user-generated-keys-for-securing-NiFi/ta-p/245551

- CentOS Linux 8
- NiFi 1.14.0
- nifi-toolkit 1.15.2

My way with NiFi TLS-toolkit:

1. Download **nifi-toolkit-*.tar.gz** to linux machine (let's ip machine is `0.0.0.1`, we need it because this VM will be as "certificateAuthorityHostname")  link [at this page](https://nifi.apache.org/download.html)

   `sudo wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/nifi/1.15.2/nifi-toolkit-1.15.2-bin.tar.gz`
2. Unarchive it

   `sudo tar -xvf nifi-toolkit-1.15.2-bin.tar.gz`
3. Generate all keys by long command

   - `../security_output` - this dir (or any other name) need to be created before run main command (it's useful to store all key-files in one place)
   - `sudo ./bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone -h` - this help-command to better understand args
   - `OU` - equal VM-names in my cluster
   - !!! `--subjectAlternativeNames` - it's main reason why raise error **javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname <ip / dns> not verified**
   - `-O` - this arg overwrite your keys in folder, be careful
   - generaet coomand: `sudo ./bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone --hostnames '0.0.0.1,0.0.0.2,0.0.0.3' -c '0.0.0.1' -C 'CN=0.0.0.1,OU=nifi-prod-cluster-01' -C 'CN=0.0.0.2,OU=nifi-prod-cluster-02' -C 'CN=0.0.0.3,OU=nifi-prod-cluster-03' -O -o ../security_output --subjectAlternativeNames '0.0.0.1,0.0.0.2,0.0.0.3,nifi-prod-cluster-01,nifi-prod-cluster-02,nifi-prod-cluster-03'`
4. After generating keys I archive full dir `security_output`:

   `sudo tar -zcvf security_output.tar.gz security_output`
5. And copy this tar/dir to other VM of cluster: to `0.0.0.2` and `0.0.0.3` in my example
6. Then we need to move `keystore.jks` and `truststore.jks` to `nifi/conf/` directory near `nifi.properties`
7. Edit `nifi.properties`. Passwords of keys will be in `security_output/0.0.0.X/nifi.properties`. I replace only this params:

   ```
   nifi.security.autoreload.enabled=false
   nifi.security.autoreload.interval=10 secs
   nifi.security.keystore=./conf/keystore.jks
   nifi.security.keystoreType=jks
   nifi.security.keystorePasswd=34dgsOBKdS+9DGHIm849ALK3JaNBdd738ddsgjfghb4J
   nifi.security.keyPasswd=34dgsOBKdS+9DGHIm849ALK3Jaddsgjfghb4J
   nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.jks
   nifi.security.truststoreType=jks
   nifi.security.truststorePasswd=/n1xI9AjcwutNBdd738uOQeQL5O9ALK3i3KwylEYMW5
   nifi.security.user.authorizer=single-user-authorizer
   nifi.security.allow.anonymous.authentication=false
   nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=single-user-provider
   nifi.security.user.jws.key.rotation.period=PT1H
   nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
   nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=
   ```
8. Restart nifi:

   `sudo service nifi restart && tail -f /opt/nifi/logs/nifi-app.log`

**UPD.** Maybe you want to set one password for keys for all machines (it's easier to setup) or set number of days for keys: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#standalone

**Links**:

- Usefull link for my guide (but old): https://pierrevillard.com/tag/tls-toolkit/
- This helps me find good idea: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Using-the-TLS-Toolkit-to-simplify-security/ta-p/247531